# Is this the best use of the Adapter pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Would using the adapter pattern be the best design to use when all you're trying to adapt to is a class that is holding fields and not methods or functions?

For example, would the following be the best way to approach this? I'm using C# if that makes any difference in your answers.

```
    NewClass 
     private Guid _guidId;

    AdpaterClass : NewClass
     private  Guid _guidId;

    LegacyClass : LegacyBaseClass
     private  Guid  _guidId;
     private  String _stringDescription;
     private  DateTime _dateTimeValue;
```

**Why am I doing this?**

I'm trying to get the LegacyClass and another Class down to the same baseline so that I can use a single common method to sort/filter on the _guidId. The common method would bring in a list of Guid's, check the _GuidId and see if it matches and then perfrom some function based on that. My goal is not to write the same sort/filter function more than once since they would be almost identical.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why are you adapting a class to just have another private instance variable?

Comment: I don't see any properties. Just fields. But sure, if you had an interface defined purely by properties, then adapting anything to that interface would require an adapter that exposed those properties...

Comment: Why not, a property is just a syntactic sugar for get/set methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like the following:

```
interface ICanHazGuidId {
    Guid GuidId { get; }
}

class NewClass : ICanHazGuidId {
    public Guid GuidId { get; private set; }
    // etc.
}

class AdapterClass : ICanHazGuidId {
    private LegacyClass legacy;
    public Guid GuidId {
        get {
            // obtain and return legacy._guidId;
        }
    }
    // constructor eating instance of LegacyClass etc.
}
```

Then just implement an `IComparer<ICanHazGuidId>` etc. If so, this would be a good use of the adapter pattern.

Comment: interface ICanHazGuidID { ... }

Comment: +1 for the clever interface naming, while staying lockstep with MS's recommended naming conventions (lead "I" for interfaces.)  Well played.